# C++ Class types in non-type template parameters: deduction guide fails

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-argument-deduction

## Problem

I am using a c++2a feature which allows structs / std::array as template arguments (`g++-9.2.0`, not supported in `clang` yet).
The feature is called `Class types in non-type template parameters` and proposed in `P0732R2`.

I try to use templates parameters of one class (struct `C` in the examples below) in order to deduce corresponding class template parameters of a second class (struct `B` in the examples below). I hereby make use of a custom class template parameter deduction guide I wrote for that specific purpose.

In this minimal example, the information I want to extract are two `int`s. 
If I use these primitive types as template parameters, everything works fine. However, when I combine the information in one `std::pair` or a custom `std::struct`, the deduction fails.

## Code

### Separated Information

The code below works just fine.

```cpp
#include <array>

/// Data structure which contains a constexpr context to be used for type deduction later
template <int aa, int ab> struct C {};

/// Class which has to find out its own type
template <std::size_t count, std::array<int, count> a, std::array<int, count> b> struct B {
  template <int... aa, int... bb> explicit B(C<aa, bb> ... c) {}
};

/// Class deduction guide
template <int... aa, int... ab> B(C<aa, ab>... c)
    ->B<sizeof...(aa) + 1, std::array<int, sizeof...(aa) + 1>{aa...},
        std::array<int, sizeof...(aa) + 1>{ab...}>;

int main() { B k{C<1, 2>{}, C<2, 3>{}}; }
```

### Combined information

The code below fails to compile.

```
#include <array>

/// Change: A contains the information from the previous example in a structs.
struct A { int a; int b; };

/// Data structure which contains a constexpr context to be used for type deduction later
template <A a> struct C {};

/// Class which has to find out its own type
template <std::size_t count, std::array<A, count> a> struct B {
  template <A... af> explicit B(C<af> ... c) {}
};

/// Class deduction guide
template <A... af> B(C<af>... c)->B<sizeof...(af) + 1, std::array<A, sizeof...(af) + 1>{af...}>;

int main() { B k{C<A{1, 2}>{}, C<A{2, 3}>{}}; }
```

The error output:

```sh
main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cc:24:14: error: class template argument deduction failed:
   24 |   B k {c1, c2};
      |              ^
main.cc:24:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘B(C<A{1, 2}>&, C<A{1, 2}>&)’
main.cc:17:20: note: candidate: ‘B(C<((const A)af)>...)-> B<(sizeof... (af) + 1), std::array<A, (sizeof... (af) + 1)>{(const A)af ...}> [with A ...af = {}]’
   17 | template <A... af> B(C<af>... c)->B<sizeof...(af) + 1, std::array<A, sizeof...(af) + 1>{af...}>;
      |                    ^
main.cc:17:20: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
main.cc:14:31: note: candidate: ‘template<long unsigned int count, std::array<A, count> a, A ...af> B(C<((const A)af)>...)-> B<count, a>’
   14 |   template <A... af> explicit B(C<af> ... c) {}
      |                               ^
main.cc:14:31: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cc:24:14: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘count’
   24 |   B k {c1, c2};
```

I now wonder what causes this problem. Does the error occur because

- ... what I want to achieve is not possible in general
- ... something is not implemented yet in g++
- ... I screwed up with my deduction guide?

I also do not understand the error message. It seems like zero arguments are expected for the function. Is the problem that `C<af>...` cannot be expanded in the constructor?

Comment: Are you compiling with `-std=c++2a`? [it works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0aWKlMa4XzUynU5C) for me

Comment: @AndyG It doesn't work with GCC 9.2.0 though, only with head. OP: That seems like a good indicator that it was just a bug in the previous version.

Comment: Yes I was compiling with `g++ -std=c++2a -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -save-temps main.cc`, but `g++ -std=c++2a main.cc` does not work for me
 either. But I will check whether it works for me for g++-10.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not try that out yet, you are right, with a more recent version of g++ it works :)
 I am new to StackOverflow; Can I accept your answer somehow / vote it up, because switching to a more recent version of g++ works for me and solves the issue. 

I've got one remaining question though: Would you report this issue to the GNU bug tracker if you were me? Because this issue seems to work in the most recent release, this seems to be fixed

Comment: I don't think you should report it to the bug tracker if the bug is already fixed in a newer version. You can accept (and upvote once you have enough reputation) if someone decides to write an actual answer from these comments. You can also write an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AndiG and @walnut anwered my question with their comments to my original question.

My issue is probably caused by a bug in my version of `G++-9`. I currently do not use the newest version of `g++-9`, the bug is solved at least in g++-10. In the version of `g++-10.0` I compiled (`3684bbb022c`) I do not receive the error anymore.